# Materialized path sorting order by date + path

Tags: mysql, materialized-path-pattern

I have database with comments (materialized path)(mysql). If i select all comm`s with "select * from comm where post_id=10 order by **path ASC**" in result i have comments from post ordered by path with older date on top and newer at bottom.

So, is there a way to select newer on top with like in disqus? if i simply "order by path DESC"  - than branch is displayed upside down - it is not what i want. 
So i need order by date(new comm on top) and path.
Thanks.!

link to bigger pic https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwIgYhO9h960ZTl4a24wNXFFQnM/view?usp=sharing

[Bigger pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbJov.gif)

Comment: Maybe is too easy, but have you tried with `ORDER BY date, path`?

Comment: @SERG Please see my answer, I'm pretty sure it is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to find the part after the first point.

Then you order DESC until the first part, and ASC after the last part.

```
SELECT * FROM comments 
  WHERE post_id=10
  ORDER by substring_index(path, '.', 1) DESC,
      path ASC
```

Note that you have an error in your attached file in the third column, inverting 9972 and 9974.

I don't know if, in this case, the MySQL optimization engine uses the index set on path to sort the result. It should be more efficient to add a column to your model.

Comment: The only usable index is one beginning with `post_id`.  `path` in an index will not help because (1) it is inside a function and (2) the mixture of DESC and ASC.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a combination of queries:

1. Create a select query where the master comments (those without a parent) are selected and ordered by descending date.
2. Combine those results with the comments having a parent record and order those entries by ascending date.

I would suggest looking into a query containing a union. That way you can combine both result sets. Downside of this could be that your query performance is impacted when you have a lot of records. If that happens you can look into self-join queries, etc.

Answer (score 0):

- I need a `depth` field that says 1 for the outer items, but >1 for the comments.
- I need a `top_of_thread` that contains the timestamp of the original posting.
- I need a timestamp for ordering.

Because of the lack of leading zeros in `path`, string comparisons won't always be right.  Hence, my request for a `timestamp`.

```
ORDER BY top_of_thread DESC, -- to get the newest thread at the top
    depth=1 DESC,  -- to sort top of thread before comments
    timestamp ASC  -- oldest comment first (or DESC?)
```

`( path LIKE '% %' )` seems to be equivalent to `( depth > 1 )` ?